# How to change Glassfish server log output in Netbeans console?

Tags: logging, netbeans, glassfish

I am developing a JavaEE application in Netbeans and deploy it to the local Glassfish instance. For logging service I use the standard java.util.logging package. Unfortunately, the default output format in the Netbeans "GlassFish Server 4.0" tab is too concise (there is even no Logger name):

```
...
INFO:   sending message
INFO:   waiting for reply
INFO:   received message
INFO:   message type: create
INFO:   create-message received
INFO:   creating client
INFO:   creating location
...
```

What Logger does the Netbeans use and where its format is set up?

I have already tried changing 
`glassfish-4.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties`
but this affects domain log files and not the Netbeans console. Setting 
`-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=...`
didn't help neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
```

change to

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

works for 3.1.2.2